# click custom option prompt function

Tags: python, prompt, python-click

I have noticed that prompt using click accepts inputs with trailing spaces

```
ftp_server = click.prompt("FTP Server")
```

Is there a way to use a custom return function like this to reject trailing spaces?

```
def custom_prompt(value):
    if value.strip():
        return True
    else:
        return False

ftp_server = click.prompt("FTP Server", custom_prompt)
```

I have already used this:

```
while not ftp_server.strip():
    ftp_server = click.prompt("FTP Server")
```

But I'm looking for a better way because I don't want to use a while loop each time I use prompt.

Comment: What is the *custom* return function expected to accomplish?

Comment: it should not accept user input if it contains trailing spaces

Comment: So you want a validator?

Comment: Yes. I have already used a while loop but I'm looking for a better way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reject invalid user input, you can use the `value_proc` parameter to [`click.prompt`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/#click.prompt).  A validator to reject input with trailing spaces could look like:

#### Prompt Validator

```
import click

def validate_no_trailing_space(value):
    if value != value.rstrip():
        raise click.UsageError("Trailing space is invalid!")
    return value

ftp_server = click.prompt("FTP Server",
                          value_proc=validate_no_trailing_space)
```

#### Trim Spaces

You might also consider a validator which trims leading and trailing spaces but reject spaces in the name:

```
def validate_no_internal_space(value):
    value = value.strip()
    if ' ' in value:
        raise click.UsageError("Spaces are not valid here!")
    return value
```

Comment: It's working and I get this : Error: Empty inputs are not allowed. But how can I delete the "Error:" part ? I want just my text to be displayed

Comment: The `Error:` is inherent to click. You would need to write your own prompt function, or handle the error outside of `click.prompt`.

Comment: And if I want to hide input in case of password ?